# Cookie set with javascript disappears after refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm setting my cookies like this:

```
document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${JSON.stringify(cookieObject)};path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure=true;expires=${someDate.toUTCString()};`
```

Everything is fine at first. But when I refresh, the cookie disappears and firefox console tells me a message:

```
Cookie “thecookiename” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute.
```

If I refresh again, the message disappears and the cookie is also gone.

Chrome acts the same, but minus the message.

**Edit**

I realized, the problem might be related to the fact, that I'm overriding the `document.cookie` setter.

```
document.setCookie = document.__lookupSetter__('cookie');
document.newCookieSetter= (cookie) => {
    // here I check, whether a cookie is allowed or not. Calls for an api endpoint to get the information.

    if (cookieDataRecieved() && cookieIsAllowed(cookie)) {
        return document.setCookie(cookie);
    }
    cacheCookie(cookie); // If cookie data has loaded, try checking again.  
}

document.__defineSetter__('cookie', document.newCookieSetter);
```

The problem applies to every cookie added through the `document.cookie = "somecookie";`

Comment: I think its just `Secure`, not `Secure=true`

Comment: The value of the cookie needs to be properly URL-encoded. That might cause some issues. That being said, do you really need to use cookies for what you are doing? Isn't [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) an option?

Comment: @Ivar Thank you for the alternative, localStorage worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The [`Secure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) attribute has no value, it's just a bare attribute (present or absent), so just replace `Secure=true` with [`Secure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies).

Comment: this does not solve the issue

Comment: are you in a HTTPS context?

Comment: Yes I am. I also updated the question.